# Get specific characters from string

Tags: c#, regex, string, linq, split

I have many string format as : RGB:ABC.XX,DEF.XX,GHI.XX where ABCDEFGHI are numbers.

I need to extract the **R** (ABC),**G** (DEF),**B** (GHI) from that String 
The problem is that the string can take many form like

```
RGB:AB.XX,DE.XX,GHI.XX
RGB:ABC.XX,DE.XX,GH.XX
RGB:ABC.XXX,DE.XX,GH.XX
RGB:ABC.XXX,DE.XX,GH.XX
...
...
...
```

So as you can see, there's many thing to consider to extract this rbg from that string.

I tried to use LINQ but that will be a mess I think (That is only for the first 'R' (red)):

```
rgb[0] = new String(rgbName.SkipWhile(x => char.IsLetter(x) || x == ':').TakeWhile(x => char.IsNumber(x)).ToArray());
```

Is there a more **efficient** way to do that? Maybe regex can do that thing but i'm not an expert. Any help will be appreciate.

Thanks.

Comment: As you're looking for an **efficient** way, best occasion to move towards becoming a RegEx expert, I'd say :-)

Comment: `ABCDEFGHI` are numbers right!

Comment: Some `string.Split`'s might be in your future...

Comment: @Anirudh ABCDEFGHI ar number yes, sorry for this.

Comment: I agree with Dave.  I would first take a substring using IndexOf and use the index of the colon + 1.  Then you would have a substring like: "ABC.XX,DE.XX,GHI.XX".  You could then use List<string> tempList = yourSubstring.Split(',').ToList(); Then you should have 3 objects in your tempList, and you can just get the values before the '.' for each string. That being said, I'm sure RegEx is probably the best solution for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Luckily, only a limited degree of regex expertship is required for this, so give it a try:

What you need to know:

- `()` encloses a capturing group - from the complete match, you will be able to extract those as single strings
- `[]` encloses a set of allowed characters
- `\.` is a fullstop (escaped, because it otherwise has a special meaning outside of `[]` in C#'s regex implementation)
- `\` in general is used for escaping special characters
- `+` means *one or more times of the preceding sub-expression*
- `^` and `$` denote the beginning and the end of the string, respectively

With that in mind, you can try the following regular expression:

```
^RGB\:([0-9]+)\.[0-9]+\,([0-9]+)\.[0-9]+\,([0-9]+)\.[0-9]+$
```

Use this to invoke the [`Match` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twcw2f1c.aspx) of the [`Regex` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.aspx).

The resulting [`Match`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.match.aspx) instance has a [`Groups` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.match.groups.aspx) which should contain four elements:

- the complete matched string
- the R part
- the G part
- the B part

Every such item is an instance of the [`Group` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.group.aspx). Use its [`Value` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.capture.value.aspx) to retrieve the matched string.

Comment: I don't understand where can the R, G, B group can be applied and read with your given regex. but thanks for the info :-)

Comment: @Sebastien: Each `([0-9]+)` is one such group. In English, it means "a capturing group containing one or more digits". So, the regular expression I arrived at looks for the literal text `RGB:`, then it expects the first such group, then a point, then another series of digits, then a comma, and so on. Each capturing group will be accessible via a `Group` instance, as described at the end of the message.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this regex

```
.*?(?<R>\d+).*?(?<G>\d+).*?(?<B>\d+)
```

You can access the group like this

```
 Regex.Match(input,regex).Groups["R"].Value;//Red value
```

Answer (score 1):

Yep, regex will be ideal but until you learn that, work with what you (and an average developer) know.

Break the problem into smaller ones
- Remove the "RGB:" part
- Split the string into an array of strings with delimiter the comma (,)
- Get the values from each string in the array

The best solution is not the one with the fewer lines of code. It's the one that can be understood by any developer who will later has to read your code.